# Why can't I implicitly convert an 'int?' to 'int'?

Tags: c#

I am trying to get Id of a table into a int variable but it is not wrking properly.

```
@foreach (var item in Model){
    int i = item.Ticket_Priority; //    actualy trying to get item.Ticket_Priority ID in integer butit is not working}
```

the error message is " Cannot implicitly convert 'int?' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing cast?)

Thank you for your support.

Comment: Which programming language is this? C# ? and what is the error message?

Comment: Is this Razor (ASP.NET MVC)? Between the @ and Model reference, it seems possible..

Comment: You'll need to supply more code for anyone to help you. What's in the Model? What is in the Item class?

Comment: yes it is in c#. 
the error message is " Cannot implicitly convert 'int?' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing cast?)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the ?? operator :

```
int? i = 2;
int i2 = i ?? 0; // ?? checks if i is null
```

Comment: Or [`GetValueOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72cec0e0(v=vs.110).aspx) ;)

Answer (score 2):

The error message gives you the information you need.

`item.Ticket_Priority` is a `Nullable<int>` or `int?` rather than just an `int`. You can use the `.HasValue` and `.Value` properties to determine if there is a value available and then use it.

```
 // assuming you want a default value of 0
 int i = item.HasValue ? item.Value : 0;
```

Comment: this can be more succintly written using the null coalescing operator: int i = item.Value??0;

Comment: I used int i = item.Ticket_priority.HasValue? item.Ticket_Priority.Value : 0;
// i did run debugger and used a breakpoint to check the result of 'i' is 0 and the value of Ticket_Priority = 3

Comment: @RobLevine Thanks for reminding me about the null coalescing operator; I rarely have an opportunity to use it :)

Comment: @HarjinderRandhawa You may have issues elsewhere with how your are populating your Model. This question was only about the compiler error you received. Feel free to open a new question more directly related to issues in the Model after you mark this one as resolved.

Comment: @Jedidja yes this is razor asp.net mvc5

Comment: @RobLevine And more semantically using the [GetValueOrDefault method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58x571cw.aspx).

Comment: @Rawling - yes; take your pick. Brevity or semantically. In fact, nine times out of ten, I prefer obvious semantic meaning, ie your suggestion.

Comment: @Jedidja won't your example will throw an exception if item is null?    Do the 0 : item.Value need to be swapped?

Comment: Thank you guys for your help it is working perfectly fine, Finaly i rewrite the same code <int i = item.Ticket_priority.HasValue? item.Ticket_Priority.Value : 0;> it works perfectly :)